# How to access local tomcat via HttpRequest from connected Android device

Tags: android, http, tomcat

While accessing from emulator works fine with:

```
  response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(
                "http://10.0.2.2:8080/DWAP/SERVLET", postParameters);
```

when I write from my Android device

```
 response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(
                "http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8080/DWAP/SERVLET", postParameters);
```

Where xx.xx.xx.xx is my public IP I do not get access to the local server.

Is there an easy way to test the app from an Android device to access the local Tomcat or do I need to test with emulator only?

Do need to go through port-fprwarding on my router or is there another way to connect "internally" on my WLAN. (Android mobile phone <-> MAC with local Tomcat)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your computer as the DMZ of the router.
This way, communication with your router (public ip) leads directly to your computer (local ip).