# Eclipse web service and Android device

Tags: android, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I'm using eclipse to run a web service written in Java EE. So the service is launched on the local network (192.168.1.1 something like that).
My Android device, connected to the computer, is connected to the WiFi. My question is : is it possible to access the web service from my Android device without publishing the service on a server ? (I cannot access it via http:// 192.168.1.1:8080/myWebService/... Because i'm not n the same network)

I've tried to use the computer network while my device is connected to it but it's seems not to be possible with Windows 7.

Comment: That solution is using a virtual device... So it's on the same network :)

Comment: i don't know if there is a difference between connection to webservice and connection to servlet, but from my device i can connect to the servlet

Comment: How do you access it ? With whiwh address ?

Comment: the ip of the computer which has the server .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i mentioned in the comments, you have to use the `IP` of the computer which has the server.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem.If u want to access localhost from your device,here is a good tutorial:
http://www.mobitechie.com/android-2/how-to-access-localhost-on-android-over-wifi/

Comment: That's a good tuto but i'm using Tomcat... So the procedure isn't the same. Is it adaptable (I've tried of course, without any success)

Comment: i have found a simailar question to yours.try it if it works for you:<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320612/how-to-access-local-tomcat-via-httprequest-from-connected-android-device>